# Why the slope of graph editor in Blender 2.92 is a straight line rather than being curve in Blender 2.8?

Tags: graph-editor

The same video tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=)

[image]ZnWsCD1Ir2s&list=PLgO2ChD7acqH5S3fCO1GbAJC55NeVaCCp&index=26

The above mentioned tutorial link is what I am following for my blender practice. In that I followed the same steps followed by the youtuber for animating by setting  the key frames and  motion path exactly the same. But I am getting the slope a straight bending line, whereas he's getting  curve which every user should get. Even when I do a basic ball bouncing animation I am getting the slope straight bending line whereas the other users are getting a beautiful curve.

Comment: As well as @moonboots' answer, setting the default, there's the 'T' shortcut for a menu to set  the interpolation of selected keyframes.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default interpolation in the *Preferences > Animation > F Curves > Default Interpolation*, switch to *Bezier*:

[image]

And as Robin says, you can switch from an interpolation mode to another one with the <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut